# Perl DBI - Set schema name as bind variable in query

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm writing a script that executes the same merge statement across several different databases. The tables names and columns are the same in each schema I am connecting to, but the schema names themselves are different. Rather than define two separate queries, what I would prefer to do is define one merge statement as a string with the schema name set to '?', and then pass in the needed schema name during execution:

`my $hostgroup_merge = "MERGE INTO ?.HOSTGROUPS .... ";`

And then later:

```
my $dev_schema  = 'DEV';
my $prod_schema = 'PROD';

#do the merge in the dev schema
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dev_server,$user,$pass);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($hostgroup_merge);
$sth->execute($dev_schema);
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect;

#now do the same merge for the prod schema
$dbh = DBI->connect($prod_server,$user,$pass);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($hostgroup_merge);
$sth->execute($prod_schema);
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect;
```

This fails with an invalid table name error:

`DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-00903: invalid table name (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 19 in '
    MERGE INTO :p1<*>.HOSTGROUPS ...`

However, it seems to be picking up the bind variable just fine, since it spits this out after the query:

`" with ParamValues: :p1='DEV']`

I know its the bind variable that's causing the problem, because when I define separate merge statements and hard-code the schema names in, they work just fine.

Since the only thing that's changing is the variable in the very beginning, I could probably hack the query together by defining the non-changing part of the statement in a string, and then concatenating the rest:

`my $dev_merge = 'MERGE INTO ' . $dev_schema . $merge_statement;`

And then just run the `prepare` on that, but is there a legitimate way to pass in the name via the query? If so, can anybody point out what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE X = ?
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE X = 'DEV'
```

so

```
MERGE INTO ?.HOSTGROUPS ....
```

is equivalent to

```
MERGE INTO 'DEV'.HOSTGROUPS ...
```

while you want

```
MERGE INTO DEV.HOSTGROUPS ...
```

Use

```
"MERGE INTO ".$dbh->quote_identifier($schema).".HOSTGROUPS ..."
```

Comment: As a small point, it's not clear that the Oracle engine throws ORA-00903 on the substituted identifier (on `'DEV'.HOSTGROUPS`), or whether it ignores the placeholder in a place placeholders can't be and errors on the unsubstituted identifier (`:p1.HOSTGROUPS`).  From the error message I'd expect the latter.  Bad schema name specification, in any case.

Comment: @pilcrow, I never claimed the substitution actually takes place. I just explained what the `?` *means*, and how it makes no sense to place it there.